# Macbook Offcie 365 get stuck in the opening page

Tags: microsoft-office, macbook

I have Office 365 installed on my Mac (Mac Ventura). For some reason, starting recently, I can't use any of the office applications. Whenever I open a file, be it Word or Excel or PowerPoint, it get stuck in the opening page and instad of show me the content of my file, it has a bland small window, seems to be a purchase popup window or something, but it doesn't have any content in it. [image] If I force quit it and open again, sometimes the problem is fixed and I can directly open the file.

Comment: It’s not a “purchase popup” it’s a popup to login into your Microsoft Account.

Comment: Try to re-install Office.

Comment: Try launching it with the Shift key held down - that will prevent it using its last saved state. Reinstalling on Mac will do absolutely nothing, unless you also clean up prefs/settings. It's simpler to just clean the prefs. It achieves the same thing.

Comment: Try to reset Office using this tool: https://office-reset.com/.